# Format inserted data in SQL with multiple inputs using the same name

Tags: php, sql, forms, input

I am trying to create a PHP form to insert data in a specific column, by using the same names in my inputs.

The form is dynamically create by requesting data from SQL, so that's why each input has the same name.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $result = $_POST['result'];


    $db = Database::connect();
    $datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $start = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO trainings (user,program,date) values(?, ?, ?)");
    $start->execute(array($userId,$id,$datenow));

    $getid = $db->query("SELECT tid AS trainingid FROM trainings WHERE user = $userId AND tid = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    $trainingIds = $getid->fetch();
    $trainingLastId = $trainingIds['trainingid'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['result']); $i++){

        $textResult = array_merge($name,$result);
        $text = implode($textResult);

        $insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE trainings SET trainings.results = '$text' WHERE tid = $trainingLastId");
        $insert->execute();
    }

    Database::disconnect();
    //header("Location: index.php");
} ?>
```

And the form :

```
            $db = Database::connect();
        global $userId;

        $exercices = $db->query("SELECT exercices.id, exercices.user, exercices.program, exercices.name, exercices.type, exercices.duration, programs.id AS program FROM exercices LEFT JOIN programs ON exercices.program = programs.id WHERE exercices.program = $id AND exercices.user = '" . $userId . "'");
        $nexercices = $exercices->fetch();
        if ($nexercices['program'] == 0){
            echo "Nothing";
        }
        else {
            $listExercices = $db->query("SELECT exercices.name, exercices.description, exercices.type, exercices.duration FROM exercices WHERE program = $id AND user = '" . $userId . "'");
            $listExercice = $listExercices->fetchAll();
            echo '<form method="post" action="" class="uk-grid-small" uk-grid>';
            foreach($listExercice AS $exercice){
                if($exercice['type'] == 'Repos'){
                    echo '<div class="uk-width-1-2@s">';
                    echo '<input class="uk-input" type="text" name="name[]" value="' . $exercice['name'] . '" readonly>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="uk-width-1-2@s">';
                    echo '<input class="uk-input" type="text" name="duration[]" value="' . $exercice['duration'] . '" readonly>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="uk-width-1-2@s">';
                    echo '<input class="uk-input" type="text" name="name[]" value="' . $exercice['name'] . '" readonly>';
                    echo '<input class="uk-input uk-form-blank" name="description[]" value="' . br2nl($exercice['description']) . '" readonly>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="uk-width-1-2@s">';
                    echo '<p>Résultat</p>';
                    echo '<input class="uk-input" type="text" name="result[]" value="">';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
            echo '<button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Create</button>';
            echo '</form>';
        }
        Database::disconnect();
```

As there is various data in SQL, it will generate an input "name" and another input "result".

Actually it's working great, but in my SQL table, I see the inserted data like this if I have two inputs for both (name and result) : `namenameresultresult`

I would like to format it like that in my sql table :

```
<p>Name : Result</p>
<p>Name : Result</p>
```

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert HTML markup? You should be doing this at output time. HTML/PHP/MySQL are all totally different animals and should be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you give me an example to make it during the output ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `for` loop to look like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['result']); $i++){
    $textResult = $name[$i]." : ".$result[$i]; 
    $insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE trainings SET trainings.results = '$textResult' WHERE tid = $trainingLastId");
    $insert->execute(); }
```

And echo it within a `<p>` tag:

```
<p><?php echo $yourrecord; ?> </p>
```

**OR**

```
$textResult = "<p>".$name[$i]." : ".$result[$i]."</p>";
```

If you must add the tag

Comment: Hello, thank you, it's working ! :) Now i have another problem, it's showing only one line, the third...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean